# How to stop ScrollView from scrolling when panning/zooming on a MapBox view?

Tags: java, android, scrollview, mapbox

I have a MapBox map placed on a scrollview, and the scrollview means I can not pan/zoom around the map.

I'm not sure if this is a bug with MapBox or whether I'm missing something, potentially obvious?

I found this issue raised in Github (https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/issues/208), but as I say, I'm not sure this actually a bug and is actually just a problem with my implementation.

Comment: Can you post your activities XML so I can review it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This snippet of code might resolve the issue for you:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    // Setup the MapView
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ....

    mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            return mapView.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Lastly, heres my XML

```
ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.cameron.mapboxplayground.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/scrollView">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Set the starting camera position and map style using xml-->
    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        mapbox:access_token="@string/accessToken"
        mapbox:style_url="@string/style_light"
        mapbox:center_latitude="40.7359"
        mapbox:center_longitude="-74.0151"
        mapbox:zoom="10"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Perfect. I needed the onTouchListener event setting up. Once again, thank you for a prompt answer. You answered my question the other day as well. Keep up the good work! MapBox has been great.

Comment: This should take place on the example page. Thx you, you saved my day :)